# Read all the files in a remote directory in perl

Tags: perl, unix

I'm new to perl. I'd like to parse through a list of log files in a remote server(unix) probably around 200mb each to create a daily report.

What is the best way to read the log files from a remote server securely using ssh and efficiently.

Any pointer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: no secret to it. you need a script on the server that does whatever you want it to do. then generally you run it from ssh or schedule it is a cron job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good Morning!
As already said in the comments there is no secret in it. I recommend you to use **Net::SSH::Perl** fo that kind of job:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use lib qw("/path/to/module/");

use Net::SSH::Perl;

my $host     = "hostname";
my $user     = "username";
my $password = "password";

my $command = 'dir /var/log/'; #your command to read the directory

my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new("$host", debug=>0);
$ssh->login("$user","$password");
my ($stdout,$stderr,$exit) = $ssh->cmd("$command"); #the standard outputs will be fetched
print $stdout; #obviously the STDOUT will be printed
```

For more informations about this Module you can read its documentation on CPAN: [Net::SSH::Perl](http://search.cpan.org/~schwigon/Net-SSH-Perl-2.01/lib/Net/SSH/Perl.pm)

I hope I could help you!

**EDIT:**
For sure you can run your script on the server and fetch its output in the same way. You just have to modify the `$command`. For example: `$command: = "perl /home/$user/my_script.pl"`.